# Emqttd Ssl Configuration

Tags: ssl, mqtt, tls1.2

I try to activate ssl of emqttd server. For this, I added following lines to emq.conf under the etc folder.

```
mqtt.listener.ssl.tls_versions = tlsv1.2,tlsv1.1,tlsv1
mqtt.listener.ssl.handshake_timeout = 15s
mqtt.listener.ssl.keyfile = etc/certs/key.pem
mqtt.listener.ssl.certfile = etc/certs/cert.pem
mqtt.listener.ssl.cacertfile = etc/certs/cacert.pem
mqtt.listener.ssl.verify = verify_peer
```

All other settings is same to default.

However, I can connect my local mqtt server without doing any ssl configuration like ssl version, certificate, etc.  by using mqtt-spy broker. I think i didn' t configure ssl properties of emqttd. How can i solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You must check which port you are trying on for SSL.
Secondly you need to place your key.pem and cert.pem at the path mentioned.
It will just work fine if client have the certificate to authenticate the server.